# Multiple show and hide buttons

Tags: javascript

I want my show more and hide button to work for multiple text contents, now it's only working for one of them. I have 12 different texts that I want to be able to show and hide with 12 different buttons, like the one in my code. How do I do this?

```js
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var button = document.getElementById("show-more");

button.onclick = function() {

  if (content.className == "open") {
    //shrink the box
    content.className = "";
    button.innerHTML = "Läs mer";
  } else {
    //expand the box
    content.className = "open";
    button.innerHTML = "Dölj";
  }

};
```

```html
<div id="content">
  Test
</div>

<a id="show-more">Läs mer</a>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem. I also suggest translating everything to English, as most StackOverflow users will not understand a specific other language.

Comment: Don't use `id` for elements that aren't unique to the page. That's what classes are for.

Comment: @PeterB That is very bad practice. Working jQuery example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/bry7wsLd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hej Linnéa!

IDs should be unique, and if you want multiple occurrences of something, you should use class names.

What I would do is to wrap the links inside of the container divs;

```
<div class="content">
    Content
    <a class="toggle" href="#">Läs mer</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
    Content
    <a class="toggle" href="#">Läs mer</a>
</div>
```

Then, instead of attaching your event listener to each anchor element, take advantage of [event propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture), and add a listener to each content wrapper instead;

```
document.querySelectorAll('.content').forEach(function(contentDiv) {
    contentDiv.onclick = function(e) {
        if(e.target.classList.contains('toggle')) {
            e.target.innerHTML = e.currentTarget.classList.contains('open') ? 'Dölj' : 'Läs mer';
            e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('open');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `class` than `id`. I have implemented simple snippet where you can design using just class names.

```js
var content = document.getElementById("content");

$(".showHide").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".more").toggle();
    if ($(this).parent().find(".more").is(":visible")) {
        $(this).text("Show less");
    } else {
        $(this).text("Show more");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
    <div class="text">
        First text1
        <div style="display:none;" class="more">Other text 1</div>
        <a class="showHide" href="#">Show more</a>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="text">
        First text2
        <div style="display:none;" class="more">Other text 2</div>
        <a class="showHide" href="#">Show more</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use document [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
var content = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".container"));

content.forEach(function(el){
    //var content= el.querySelector(".content");
    var button = el.querySelector(".show-more");
    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        el.classList.toggle("open");
        el.classList.contains("open") ? (button.innerHTML = "Dölj") : (button.innerHTML = "Läs mer");
           
    }, false)
});
```

```css
.container .content{display: none}
.container.open .content{display: block}
```

```html
<section>
  <article class="container">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</p>
      <p class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
      <a class="show-more">Läs mer</a>
  </article>

  <article class="container">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</p>
      <p class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
      <a class="show-more">Läs mer</a>
  </article>
  
   <article class="container">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</p>
      <p class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
      <a class="show-more">Läs mer</a>
  </article>
  
   <article class="container">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</p>
      <p class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
      <a class="show-more">Läs mer</a>
  </article>
  
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work for multiple paragraphs if you use classes for all elements, and then process it from there as element pairs (`div` + corresponding `button`).

I deliberately kept everything as much as possible the same as your original code, so it would be easy to understand the changes. And I added some 'hidden' content so you really see something happening.

```js
var contentDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("show-more");

for (var i = 0; i < contentDivs.length; i++) {
  // "let" creates locally scoped variables for use in the function.
  let div = contentDivs[i];
  let button = buttons[i];
  button.onclick = function() {
    if (div.className == "open") {
      //shrink the box
      div.className = "content";
      button.innerHTML = "Read more";
    } else {
      //expand the box
      div.className = "open";
      button.innerHTML = "Close";
    }
  };
}
```

```css
div, a { font-size: 14px; }
.content { overflow: hidden; max-height: 18px }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  Div 1<br />.....<br />.....<br />.....
</div>
<a class="show-more">Read more</a>
<hr size="1">

<div class="content">
  Div 2<br />.....<br />.....<br />.....
</div>
<a class="show-more">Read more</a>
<hr size="1">
```